# How to get request.session inside ActionCable Channel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Is there a way to get (or pass from `Connection`) request data(actually, I need `session[:_csrf_token]`, don't ask why) in the `Channel`? For example:

```rb
class MeetingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    session[:_csrf_token]
  end
end
```

For now, I could only get `csrf_token` in `Connection`:

```rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    def connect
      puts "**********************************************************"
      puts "CSRF token: #{request.session[:_csrf_token]}"
      puts "**********************************************************"
    end
  end
end
```

It outputs (when connecting):

```
**********************************************************
CSRF token: u33bsVI7HnF2bqWRfkriQUlLzIUpCcDVovgRTAkoGKM=
**********************************************************
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the connection, we create this method (because of `@request` being private):

```
def session
  @request.session
end
```

Then, in the channel you can access the session like so:

```
session = connection.session
```